How to embed Python (3.12) sub-interpreters in threaded C++ runtime?
Python 3.12 exposes C-API of the sub-interpreter mechanism. I'm trying to use this new feature for a threaded task scheduling written in C++, but lacking a full understanding, I'm running into difficulties (I have experience with embedded Lua, but Python's context is very different ...; I'm guided by the https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.12/Modules/_xxsubinterpretersmodule.c example).
My setup is:

C++ task scheduler running on worker threads;
Agents (C++ classes) with tasks (methods) to be executed on the worker threads:


tasks of different agents are executed in parallel;
tasks within the same agent are executed sequentially (i.e. access to their agent state is disjoint (i.e. no race conditions).

The challenge is:

At the agent level I want to maintain a Python (thread?) state that is updated by the task methods calling into the agent's Python sub-interpreter.
Python sub-interpreters of different agents should be able to run in parallel.

This is what I have so far:
#include <Python.h>
#include <interpreteridobject.h>

static PyInterpreterConfig py_config = {
        .use_main_obmalloc = 0,
        .allow_fork = 0,
        .allow_exec = 0,
        .allow_threads = 1,
        .allow_daemon_threads = 0,
        .check_multi_interp_extensions = 1,
        .gil = PyInterpreterConfig_OWN_GIL,
};

class Agent {
  PyThreadState* py_thread;
  PyStatus py_status;
  PyInterpreterState* py_interp;
  PyObject* py_interp_id;

  Agent() {
    // PyThreadState *save_tstate = PyThreadState_Get();
    this->py_status = Py_NewInterpreterFromConfig(
                            &this->py_thread, &py_config);
    // assert(this->py_thread != NULL);  // FAILS
    // PyThreadState_Swap(save_tstate);
    this->py_interp = PyThreadState_GetInterpreter(this->py_thread);
    this->py_interp_id = _PyInterpreterState_GetIDObject(this->py_interp);
    // assert(this->py_interp_id != NULL); // FAILS
};

}

Some of my questions are:

Will I be able to use a Python interpreter at the agent (thread) level in the agent tasks to be executed on (load-balanced) workers (i.e. varying worker threads)?
Does the subinterpreter mechanism start with a central Python (mother) thread?

Any guidance to help me implement in Python the above (... if possible ...) is much appreciated.
